# Is there anything I can do to make tweets not appear "automated"?

Tags: twitter

I have a private, protected twitter feed which I use to test images before they are tweeted to a corporate Twitter account, to make sure they will appear as intended (for example, checking that Twitter's [auto-cropping algorithm for the preview pane](http://www.tweetbrander.com/crop-images-in-twitter-for-preview-pane/) doesn't crop them in an unfortunate way).

This twitter account naturally has rather unusual usage patterns, and Twitter's robot-spotting robot has decided I'm a robot. It blocks my tweets with this message:

> This request looks like it might be automated. To protect our users from spam and other malicious activity, we can't complete this action right now. Please try again later.

Are there any known techniques or facts about how this Twitter algorithm works that I can use to avoid spooking the robot-spotting-robot, and convince Twitter that I am in fact a human being?

I've found a short-term workaround to get un-stuck when this happens - I changed my password and logged in again, and suddenly I was unblocked. No idea why.

But I still don't know what to do to prevent this happening in future.

Answer (score 2):

Do spamming but in a smart way, increase the time frame of your tweets and do not post links with each and every post. unable your automated software sometimes in a week to tell the twitter that this a/c is a genuine a/c.